# Toolbar text lowercase after adding this line <bool name="abc_config_actionMenuItemAllCaps"/> in pre lollipop devices, why?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-menu

I was using using one menu item text as Login
But in toolbar it was showing Like LOGIN. I also tried 
@style/AppTheme.Widget.ActionButton

false

and

    false

but that does not work for me. But after adding this line

it coming correct Login why, Pls explain me.
Thanks.